# Expand the functionality of wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I would like to create a GUI with Visual Studio which is composed mainly by a Treeview and a canvas. The functionality of the application is initially to create somewhat complicated shapes on the canvas which should be connected later in order to construct a compact unit (the final purpose is not graphical, but represent functions and procedures). More particularly, the user would have the possibility by a shape selection on the Treeview to click on the canvas and the respective shape to be drawn. He has also the possibility to move the shapes on the canvas and to connect them with lines. It becomes apparent that the application should make extended use of mouselisteners (mouseEvents).

Is a wpf the appropriate type of project to accomplish something like that?

Given that they shapes are not plain but they contain contents, other shapes, buttons and mouseEvents, the code demanded for their creation is not confined. Should it be entirely in the MainWindow.xaml.cs or it would be better directed to split the implementation to more classes (e.g. one separate class for each shape)? For example the code for the Rectangle is so far:

```
Double rectWidth = 100;
Double rectHeight = rectWidth;

shapeToRender = new Rectangle() { Fill = Brushes.Red, Height = 100, Width = 100, RadiusX = 7, RadiusY = 7 };
shapeToRender.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
shapeToRender.StrokeThickness = 3;
currentShape = SelectedShape.Empty;

Canvas.SetLeft(shapeToRender, e.GetPosition(canvasDrawingArea).X - rectWidth / 2);
Canvas.SetTop(shapeToRender, e.GetPosition(canvasDrawingArea).Y - rectHeight / 2);

canvasDrawingArea.Children.Add(shapeToRender);

double xCircle1 = e.GetPosition(canvasDrawingArea).X + (rectWidth)/2;
double yCircle1 = e.GetPosition(canvasDrawingArea).Y + (rectHeight)/4;
double xCircle2 = xCircle1;
double yCircle2 = e.GetPosition(canvasDrawingArea).Y - (rectWidth) / 4;
double xCircle3 = e.GetPosition(canvasDrawingArea).X - rectWidth / 2;
double yCircle3 = e.GetPosition(canvasDrawingArea).Y;

Ellipse s1Ellipse = new Ellipse() { Fill = Brushes.Yellow, Height = 10, Width = 10 };
Canvas.SetLeft(s1Ellipse, xCircle1-5);
Canvas.SetTop(s1Ellipse, yCircle1-5);

canvasDrawingArea.Children.Add(s1Ellipse);

Ellipse s2Ellipse = new Ellipse() { Fill = Brushes.Yellow, Height = 10, Width = 10 };
Canvas.SetLeft(s2Ellipse, xCircle2-5);
Canvas.SetTop(s2Ellipse, yCircle2-5);

canvasDrawingArea.Children.Add(s2Ellipse);

Ellipse s3Ellipse = new Ellipse() { Fill = Brushes.Yellow, Height = 10, Width = 10 };
Canvas.SetLeft(s3Ellipse, xCircle3 - 5);
Canvas.SetTop(s3Ellipse, yCircle3 - 5);

canvasDrawingArea.Children.Add(s3Ellipse);
```

Is it reasonable to build a separate class that is responsible to create the rectangles? How could then I manipulate elements of the MainWindow and the mousEvents inside the new class?

Answer (score 0):

From what you've wrote WPF is exactly what you need. IMHO you should create class (custom control) to represent your diagram items. You don't necessary need to write different class for every shape on diagram. If the look is all that is different you can always use different templates to change the representation of your diagram control.

How to build such a thing is rather complex question. I've came across a very useful article on creating diagram designer in WPF. It is actually a set of articles. They would be a good place to start. [Here's the link for the last article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx) (because it contains links to previous articles).